# How to convert a json into a posgresql.JSONB type

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to write a json binary object to my database. My struct is defined as

```golang
type Configs struct {
    ID     uint64           `db:"id"`
    Config postgresql.JSONB `db:"config"`
}
```

In my main code, I have:

```golang
var configToSend Configs

c, _ := json.Marshal(`{"Hello": "World"}`)

configToSend.Config = c
```

However, I am unable to convert the output from `json.Marshal` directly into `postgresql.JSONB`. How can I do this?

Comment: which package is that postgresql package

Comment: @keser `upper.io/db.v3/postgresql`

Comment: AFAICT `postgresql.JSONB` expects a Go value to be un/marshaled, it does not expect already marshaled json data.

Comment: In general you should not pass raw json bytes as `postgresql.JSONB`, but if you have to you can do so by converting the `[]byte` into `json.RawMessage`, e.g. `configToSend.Config.V = json.RawMessage(c)`.

Comment: @mkopriva i made a mistake in the string. updated the question

Comment: @JohnTan ok but do you really want to marshal a string? In Go you generally marshal some struct value, or a map, or a slice, but *not* plain strings.

Comment: @JohnTan the string already seems to be valid json, are you sure you want to marshal that into json? Are you aware of what the output of that looks like?

Comment: @mkopriva yes i understand what you are saying. I was using the string as a simple example. u are right, i do want to marshall a struct instead

Comment: @JohnTan in that case you don't need to marshal that struct yourself, `postgresql.JSONB` will do that for you, all you need to do is `configToSend.Config.V = structValue`.

Comment: @JohnTan here: https://github.com/upper/db/blob/v3/postgresql/custom_types.go#L90 you can see that `json.Marshal` is called for you (note that the `Value()` method is invoked automatically when a value of the receiver type is being saved to the database). So you do not need to call `json.Marshal` yourself, all you need to do is store the struct value into the [`V`](https://github.com/upper/db/blob/v3/postgresql/custom_types.go#L44) field of the `JSONB` type.